# What are the practical applications of Stop & Wait, Selective Repeat and Go Back N?

Tags: protocol-theory

What are the practical applications when to use Stop and Wait, Selective Repeat, and Go Back N?  What in real life protocols are implemented using these mechanisms?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The TCP protocol implements these algorithms, with some slight variations.